# Webflux : ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint - ReactiveSecurityContextHolder is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, reactive-programming

I was trying to get SecurityContext::getAuthentication as follow:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, AuthenticationException authException) {

        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty")))
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .flatMap(a -> { return Mono.empty();});}
```

however, the context is empty. looks like the reactive chain was broken.

here is a snippet of the securityconfig:

```
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

   private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http
                .csrf().disable()

                .authorizeExchange()
                ...

                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)

               ...

        return http.build();
    }
```

wonder if there is anything missing or if there is another way to get the context within the authenticationEntryPoint.